# Laravel deployment with Forge - VIte manifest not found

Tags: php, laravel, vite

I am trying to deploy a brand new Laravel 9 site with Vite.

I have the site running locally just fine, and the deployment is running via Laravel forge using the default deployment script:

```bash
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin $FORGE_SITE_BRANCH

$FORGE_COMPOSER install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

( flock -w 10 9 || exit 1
    echo 'Restarting FPM...'; sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload ) 9>/tmp/fpmlock

if [ -f artisan ]; then
    $FORGE_PHP artisan migrate --force
fi
```

Before pushing my changes from my local to remote server, I run:

```
npm run build
```

However, when the site has been deployed to forge, I get the below error:

> (Exception(code: 0): Vite manifest not found at: /home/forge/default/public/build/manifest.json at /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php:139)

When I ssh into my server, this is the content of the `/public` folder:

```
.
└── public/
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── index.php
    └── robots.txt
```

Shouldn't the `/build` folder be available on the production site as well, or am I missing something? Please note in my standard generated `.gitignore` file, these paths are excluded:

```
/public/build
/public/hot
/public/storage
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### EDIT 07-02-2023:

I ended up changing my `.gitignore`. I removed the below:

```
/public/build
/public/hot
/public/storage
```

And added the below:

```
!/public/build
/public/hot
/public/storage
```

Which also fixed the issue.

## Original answer:

I fixed this by updating the deployment script on Laravel Forge to include `npm install` and `npm run build`:

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin $FORGE_SITE_BRANCH

$FORGE_COMPOSER install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

( flock -w 10 9 || exit 1
    echo 'Restarting FPM...'; sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload ) 9>/tmp/fpmlock

if [ -f artisan ]; then
    $FORGE_PHP artisan migrate --force
fi

npm install
npm run build
```

I looked at [this reply](https://github.com/innocenzi/laravel-vite/discussions/267) to a similar question, which basically states:

> Asset building for production is a known problem that has multiple known solutions:
>
> 1. You build your assets locally and commit them to Git
> 2. You let your deployment script (and server) build the assets for you
> 3. You build your assets locally, publish them to the cloud, and tell your deployment script to download them

I chose option 2 :)